# Offset error at the launch of a nodejs api application

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I'm setting up an api application based on NodeJS and the ORM Sequelize. Everything work fine on my local computer (Windows), but when I want to install this app on a AWS EC2 Linux Instance, I'm encountering this error at the launch of the app :

```
internal/buffer.js:53
  throw new ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE(type || 'offset',
  ^

RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 5. Received 9
    at boundsError (internal/buffer.js:53:9)
    at Uint8Array.readUInt32LE (internal/buffer.js:109:5)
    at Packet.readInt32 (/home/ec2-user/live/CodexAvatarAPI/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:103:24)
    at Function.fromPacket (/home/ec2-user/live/CodexAvatarAPI/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/handshake.js:59:32)
    at ClientHandshake.handshakeInit (/home/ec2-user/live/CodexAvatarAPI/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/client_handshake.js:92:40)
    at ClientHandshake.execute (/home/ec2-user/live/CodexAvatarAPI/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:39:22)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/home/ec2-user/live/CodexAvatarAPI/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:449:32)
    at PacketParser.Connection.packetParser.p [as onPacket] (/home/ec2-user/live/CodexAvatarAPI/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:72:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/ec2-user/live/CodexAvatarAPI/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.Connection.stream.on.data (/home/ec2-user/live/CodexAvatarAPI/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:79:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

I've done some research but found nothing useful for now. To my understanding (i'm a beginner with node), the problem seems to be more in the mysql2 component than in the core of NodeJS itself, but I'm not sure where to search exactly.

This error happen juste before synchronizing the database structure with what has been defined in the code. Normally I have to see database update at this point.

Comment: Do you able to solve it?

Comment: No, I'm still stuck, and I have to go over on another project, it was for personnel project and i did not work on it for now.